# Carousel multi previous button

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

In http://www.bootply.com/Y30udsQ35V. I already tried to fix the prev button behavior, for he has the same behavior the next button, however, I am unable to fix.

Comment: Please explain problem in more detail as well as post your code within the question itself. As far as I can see the 2 buttons seem to work as would be expected

Comment: When you click the button prev, in the background the images run 100% of the route and in front it runs 25%. In the next button both in the background as the front the images run 25% of the route.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve the problem is added the following code in the css file:

```
.item.right:not(.prev) {visibility: hidden;}
```

The css file would be as follows:

```
.carousel-control            { width:  4%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {margin-left:15px;background-image:none;}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -100%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  100%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -100%; }
    .active > div { display:none; }
    .active > div:first-child { display:block; }
    .item.right:not(.prev) {visibility: hidden;}
}
@media (min-width: 767px) and (max-width: 992px ) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -50%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  50%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -50%; }
    .active > div { display:none; }
    .active > div:first-child { display:block; }
    .active > div:first-child + div { display:block; }
    .item.right:not(.prev) {visibility: hidden;}
}
@media (min-width: 992px ) {
    .carousel-inner .active.left { left: -25%; }
    .carousel-inner .next        { left:  25%; }
    .carousel-inner .prev        { left: -25%; }    
    .item.right:not(.prev) {visibility: hidden;}
}
```